# Why is cosine used to calculate the x values and sine the y values for an arc?

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, trigonometry, graphing

I'm trying to understand the math on this raphael.js demo:

http://raphaeljs.com/pie.js

Checkout the sector method:

```
function sector(cx, cy, r, startAngle, endAngle, params) {
    var x1 = cx + r * Math.cos(-startAngle * rad),
        x2 = cx + r * Math.cos(-endAngle * rad),
        y1 = cy + r * Math.sin(-startAngle * rad),
        y2 = cy + r * Math.sin(-endAngle * rad);
    return paper.path(["M", cx, cy, "L", x1, y1, "A", r, r, 0, +(endAngle - startAngle > 180), 0, x2, y2, "z"]).attr(params);
}
```

This is the actual demo:
http://raphaeljs.com/pie.html

My math is a little rusty and I'm trying to understand the sector function - given the startAngle and endAngle parameters (each start and end point values between 0 and 360 drawing an arc), why does this function work?

Comment: *Don't* try mathoverflow.net for something like this -- and @Steven *please* don't recommend doing so unless the question really is "graduate research level" math. Try the [StackExchange math site](http://math.stackexchange.com) instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It all depends on how you treat `startAngle` and `endAngle`. It looks like this is treating them as starting from horizontal to the right (i.e. an angle of 0 is pointing East) and going clockingwise (so an angle of 45 degrees is pointing South-East.

Usually in mathematics we consider angles starting from the horizontal to the right, but increasing anti-clockwise... but if you ask a non-mathematician to draw an angle, they may well treat it from vertically up (i.e. North) increasing clockwise. This looks like it's taking a mixture :) There's no really "wrong" or "right" answer here - it's all a matter of definition.

As pictures are popular, here are the three systems I've described, each assuming the line is of length `r`:

**Normal mathematics: anti-clockwise from x-axis**

[image: First diagram]
<sub>(source: [arachsys.com](http://yoda.arachsys.com/blogfiles/so/angles-1.png))</sub>

**Asking the man on the street to draw an angle (clockwise from y-axis)**

[image: Second diagram]

**The angles used by this code (clockwise from x-axis)**

[image: Third diagram]

Comment: Jon, what did you use to generate the lovely picture with the hand-written but legible quality?  I've used Zwibbler in the past for such things: http://zwibbler.com/

Comment: @duffymo: A piece of paper, a pen, and a scanner.

Comment: True genius == simplicity.  Nice.

Comment: I didn't know angles had directions. Clears up a lot, thank you.

Comment: Just for clarity, this are the coordinates used in the Canvas from HTML5, angles are clockwise and start from the x axis.

Answer (score 14):

Just look at what sin and cos actually **mean** in a circle:
[image]

If you have a point on a circle which forms an angle alpha, the cos alpha is the x-part of the point a sin alpha is the y part.

This illustration explains, why the angle is negated. 
[image]

It means, that you can now specify **clockwise** angles, which most people with analogue clocks prefer.

Comment: @Luther: As I said in my answer, it entirely depends on how you've decided to treat angles. There's nothing *inherently* x-axis-related about `cos` - it's only because that diagram measures angles from the x-axis.

Comment: (In particular, this diagram *doesn't* explain why the angle is negated each time.)

Comment: What do you mean by negated? Thanks.

Comment: @apphacker: Look at the code: `r * Math.cos(-startAngle * rad)`. It's taking `cos` of `-startAngle`, not `startAngle`. I believe that's due to the angle being measured *clockwise*. See my answer for more details.

Comment: It was really a combination of all these answers and comments that helped me, but the diagram really made it easier. Thank you.

Comment: @apphacker: I now have diagrams which *don't* involve trying to read mirror-writing... see if they help any more :)

Comment: @duffymo: Oh, the credit has to go to wikimedia. I did only the flipping :-)

Answer (score 2):

Because arbitrary point on circumference with center (cx, cy)  and radius R has the following coordinate (it directly follows from cos and sin geometric definitions - ratio between lengths of corresponding cathetus and hypotenuse):

```
x = cx + R*cos(a)
y = cy + R*sin(a) for  0 <= a < 2π
```

So setting limits on angle a you can define arbitrary arc.

Answer (score 1):

If you take 0° as horizontal with x increasing and 90° as vertical with y increasing then as:

```
cos(0) = 1
sin(0) = 0

cos(90) = 0
sin(90) = 1
```

you can vary the x value by multiplying it by the cosine and vary the y value by multiplying it by the sine.